# How do I document a method that returns a tuple in javadoc?

Tags: java, tuples, javadoc

How do I document in `javadoc` a method that returns a `tuple`? For example:

```
    public Tuple2<Double,Double> arcadeDrive(double moveValue, double rotateValue, boolean ... sqrdRooted){
            //Code
            return new Tuple2<Double,Double>(leftMotorSpeed, -rightMotorSpeed);
```

I know how to document the `parameters` and everything, but I'm not sure how I should be representing the `tuple` returned. So far I've been using something similar to

```
/**
 * Commands for classic arcade drive.
 * 
 * @param moveValue The speed (-1.0 ~ +1.0) to move in the Y direction at.
 * @param rotateValue The speed (-1.0 ~ +1.0) to move in the Y direction at.
 * @param sqrdRooted Squares the inputs if true
 * @return (leftMotorSpeed, -rightMotorSpeed) Speed the Left motors are to be set to, Speed the right motors are to be set to
 */
```

Comment: This is primarily a matter of opinion. As per [the `@return` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#return): _"This text should describe the return type and permissible range of values."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be:

@return a new tuple object ***describe the purpose of the returned object***

You don't really need to insert the entire variable type. Just describe what it is returning and why in normal speech.